# Linux AutoNeoGrub0.mbr is corrupt of missing?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, mbr

I've been trying to get my windows boot manager working so I can boot both Windows 7 and Linux. Currently, I can boot both, but only run when I click on "Windows 7" in the boot manager (Linux will run if my external hard drive with it is plugged in).

When I click on the Linux option I made with EasyBCD, it just says windows failed to start and the AutoNeoGrub0.mbr is missing or corrupt.

I've already tried reinstalling Grub2 and giving it updates through the terminal. The same problem still remains.

Anything I can do to fix it?